# set limit on how much space an hostpath volume can consume

Tags: kubernetes

I use a volume with hostPath, so I can share files between my local host and the pods. My question is: Is there a way to limit how much sapce an hostpath volume can consume by those pods, like ephemeral storage request/limit? What happens if the container consumed all space on host's local directory?

```
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: "/search/data/app"
        name: app
```

Comment: I would try create separate LVM partitions and use their mount points as a Pod's Hostpath target directory. In that case container won't consume more than the LVM partition size. It may add some maintenance cost though. Consider to use iscsi volumes as an alternative storage option. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#iscsi

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not a current feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it a kubernetes future feature? or Is there much difficulty in implementing this feature now?

Comment: Aside from some specific cases like log collectors, `hostPath:` volumes aren't something you should be using for general-purpose storage.  The other volume types have more controls, and if you use the PersistentVolumeClaim mechanism, the storage will often be able to "follow" your pod if it gets rescheduled on a different node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean, In our cluster, hostpath ```/search/data/app``` and kubelet root path ```/search/data/kubelet_root``` are on the same SSD ```/dev/sbd```. The containers are able to consume all space of ```/dev/sdb```, causing pod evictions, which is an undesirable result.

Comment: We have ceph RBD, but In some I/O sensitive user cases, we can only use local storage on nodes.

Comment: Do you have the same SSD physically attached to every node in the cluster?  How do you not misplace the data if the pod gets deleted or rescheduled?

Comment: @DavidMaze We use statefulset to pull data from external storage to the nodes' storage which was mounted by hostpath, like ```/search/data/app```, the user's pod then loads the data into memory and starts to run. So we need to try to avoid pod being evicted or rescheduled. Besides, all pods in the cluster have the same priority, so that no pod would be preempted.

Answer (score 0):

@coderanger and @DavidMaze are right* but I would like to back it up with some more context.

> A [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's
> filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will
> need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.
>
> For example, some uses for a `hostPath` are:
>
> - running a container that needs access to Docker internals; use a `hostPath` of `/var/lib/docker`
> - running cAdvisor in a container; use a `hostPath` of /sys
> - allowing a Pod to specify whether a given `hostPath` should exist prior to the Pod running, whether it should be created, and what it
>   should exist as

`hostPath` is not recommended due to several reasons:

- You don't directly control which node your pods will run on, so you're not guaranteed that the pod will actually be scheduled on the node that has the data volume.
- You expose your cluster to security threats.
- If a node goes down you need the pod to be scheduled on other node where your locally provisioned volume will not be available.

And regarding the potential [limiting of the `hostPath` volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#resources):

> The storage media (such as Disk or SSD) of an `emptyDir` volume is
> determined by the medium of the filesystem holding the kubelet root
> dir (typically `/var/lib/kubelet`). **There is no limit on how much
> space an `emptyDir` or `hostPath` volume can consume, and no isolation
> between containers or between pods.**

*as always :)

**EDIT:**

Including the suggestion from VASャ and making the answer a community wiki one.

> I would try create separate LVM partitions and use their mount points
> as a Pod's Hostpath target directory. In that case container won't
> consume more than the LVM partition size. It may add some maintenance
> cost though. Consider to use [iscsi](http://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#iscsi) volumes as an alternative
> storage option.